# Can Apache handle + (plus) sign for space in URL?

Tags: apache, file, url, space, url-encoding

My PHP web app generates URL's for **files** (images) where it puts `+` (plus) sign instead of space in the file name due to function `urlencode()`. But Apache doesn't translate `+` to space, it throws a 404 error. When I use `rawurlencode()`, spaces are encoded with `%20`, which works.

But I like `+` sign in URL more :) how to set Apache to recognize it? Or is it a bad idea?

Thank you.

Comment: That's the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, which is legal in query strings, but not for the main URL, so I would be surprised if Apache had an easy way to enable that for the URL, not the query string (and you probably don't _really_ want to do it if it's possible, either).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a bad idea to have `+` sign in URL path. Especially in a filename where `+` can be a regular part of the filename. So path `ab+cd.jpg` would be ambiguous. Apache couldn't say if the browser requests a file `ab cd.jpg` or `ab+cd.jpg`.